# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected (after some calls of Process.GetProcessByID by WinEventProc)

Tags: c#, user32

I need your guidance masters.
Bellow follow my code. I'm capturing the title of the window when the event 3 or 8 occur and creating a counter when the event 9 occur.

My code is working great, but, when I try to get the name of the owner of windows' exe with my function GetProcessName, I'm receiving the error "CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected".  I already did and tried all I knowed, but nothing resolve the error. The error occur after some time of start the use of the application.

When I not call my function  GetProcessName, the error not happen.

```
    delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;
    private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND = 9;
    private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART = 8;
    int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND, IntPtr.Zero, new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc), 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        try
        {

            if (eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND || eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART && idObject == 0)
            {

                aux1 = GetActiveWindowTitle(hwnd);//A function tha get a name of the title of the window
                if (aux1 != aux2 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(aux1) == false)
                {
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
                    pnomelast = GetProcessName((int)pid);//This is the function!!

                    aux2 = aux1;
                    aux1 = "";
                }
            }
            else if (eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        };
    }

    public static string GetProcessName(int processId)
    {
        try
        {
            return Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainModule.FileName.ToString().Split('\\').Last();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that SetWinEventHook is creating a new delegate on the fly which has no reference. Since it is orphaned, it will be destroyed on the next garbage collection.

First create a new WinEventDelegate

```
private static winEventDelegate = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);
```

Then change:

```
SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND, IntPtr.Zero, new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc), 0, 0, 0);
```

TO:

```
SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND, IntPtr.Zero, winEventDelegate, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I did how you said, but the error happen yet. When I not call my function to get the process, the problem not happen.  I think the problem has a relation with de use of  Process.GetProcessById.

Comment: `WinEventDelegate dele = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc); 
  SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND, IntPtr.Zero, dele, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I made a complete and compact version of the code, that represents the problem, the error happen when the Process.GetProcessById is called. Thanks.

```
namespace stackoverflow1    {
public partial class Form1 : Form    {

    delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;
    private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART = 8;
    uint pid = 0;
    string pnamelast = "";


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WinEventDelegate dele = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc); 
        SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART, IntPtr.Zero, dele, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        try
        {
            if (eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND || eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART && idObject == 0)
            {
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
                pnamelast = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid).MainModule.FileName.ToString().Split('\\').Last();
                textBox1.AppendText(pnamelast + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
      }
    }
  }
```